# How to manage options in PySpark more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, design-patterns

Let us consider following pySpark code

```
my_df = (spark.read.format("csv")
                     .option("header","true")
                     .option("inferSchema", "true")
                     .load(my_data_path))
```

This is a relatively small code, but sometimes we have codes with many options, where passing string options causes typos frequently. Also we don't get any suggestions from our code editors.
As a workaround I am thinking to create a named tuple (or a custom class) to have all the options I need. For example,

```
from collections import namedtuple
allOptions = namedtuple("allOptions", "csvFormat header inferSchema")
sparkOptions = allOptions("csv", "header", "inferSchema")
my_df = (spark.read.format(sparkOptions.csvFormat)
                     .option(sparkOptions.header,"true")
                     .option(sparkOptions.inferSchema, "true")
                     .load(my_data_path))
```

I am wondering if there is downsides of this approach or if there is any better and standard approach used by the other pySpark developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `.csv` function to read the file, options are named arguments, thus it throws the TypeError. Also, on VS Code with Python plugin, the options would autocomplete.

```py
df = spark.read.csv(my_data_path,
                    header=True,
                    inferSchema=True)
```

If I run with a typo, it throws the error.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/tv/32xjg80x6pb_9t4909z8_hh00000gn/T/ipykernel_3636/4060466279.py in <module>
----> 1 df = spark.read.csv('test.csv', inferSchemaa=True, header=True)

TypeError: csv() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inferSchemaa'
```

On VS Code, options are suggested in autocomplete.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Emma. You are correct when using using a specific reader like csv as you mentioned in your example. However, my question is for more generic  spark.read.format, where we pass the reader and then other options. I have to use this (as I used in my example) API to read and write as my program will decide the format to read/write at runtime.

Comment: I see. sorry, it wasn't clear that you have to use the `load` function.  
`option` function is not fail proof, it takes any string key, so `namedtuple` would make it better but it is not completely giving you the correct error. 

I think you can either write your own wrapper with named arg or you could try using specific readers by having if-else/match on  `format` you receive from the caller.

Answer (score 0):

For that and many other reasons, in production level projects, we used to write a project to wrap spark.

So developers not allowed to deal with spark directly.

In such project we can :

- Abstract options using enumerations and inheritance to avoid typos and incompatibles options.
- Set default options for each data format and developers can overwrite them if needed, to reduce the amount of code written by the developer
- Set and defines any repetitive code like frequently used data sources, default output data format, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to make a wrapper(s) with some default values and kwargs like this

```py
def csv(path, inferSchema=True, header=True, options={}):
    return hdfs(path, 'csv', {'inferSchema': inferSchema, 'header': header, **options})

def parquet(path, options={}):
    return hdfs(path, 'parquet', {**options})

def hdfs(path, format, options={}):
    return (spark
        .read
        .format(format)
        .options(**options)
        .load(f'hdfs://.../{path}')
    )
```